# UIActionSheet height is 4 inch on a 3.5 inch device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiactionsheet

I am currently updating my app to support 4 inch iPhone 5 screen. In that attempt I am stuck at this point where I am opening a UIActionSheet and it works fine and show all buttons on iPhone 5 4 inch screen but on a 3.5 inch device the last button is cutting out. Which indicates that UIActionSheet doesn't recognise smaller screen.

This is what I am doing in my code. Any idea?

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery;
// Code to initialize UIActionSheet

popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
[popupQuery showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[popupQuery release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Check that the option 'Full Screen at Launch' is checked on the Window in you MainWindow.xib.

I had a similar problem and others when updating for iPhone 5 screen. Apparently the 'Simulated metrics' of Window will be the actual metrics when launching (provided you have not checked 'Full Screen at Launch').

Apple actually has a Note about it in the [UIWindow Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html):

> ... If you choose to create a window in Interface Builder, be sure to select the Full Screen at Launch option in the Attributes inspector so that the window is sized appropriately for the current device. ...